# What are difference between import utility.* and only need fun in Android?

Tags: java, android

There are many fun in my utility, there are two method ways to import.

Method A is simple

Method B is only import need fun

What are difference between Method A and Method B?

Will Method A increase the size of APK package?

**Method A**

```
import utility.*
```

**Method B**

```
import utility.fun1
import utility.fun2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`import utility.`***

> Imports all classes of package

**`import utility.fun1`**

> Imports only fun1 of the package

**There are pros & cons with both:**

- If you use two or more classes from a package, then import the whole package is considered good idea. Long lists of imports are daunting to the reader.It would be daunting for the reader of code to have huge number of imports (Although Android Studio helps to group them). So the wildcard imports could be a better choice here.
- However, wildcard imports can sometimes cause name conflicts and ambiguities. Two classes with the same name, but in different packages, will need to be specifically imported, or at least specifically qualified when used.

> Will Method A increase the size of APK package?

This doesn't impact Size of APK. Unused imports have a trivial impact on the compiler, but there are no imports in the byte code or at runtime. Unused imports have no performance impact at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

**Method A**

```
import utility.*
```

Here * simply means import all the classes inside `utility` package

**Method B**

```
import utility.fun1
import utility.fun2
```

Here `utility.fun1` means you are specifically import ONLY `fun1` of `utility` package

Your question

> Will Method A increase the size of APK package?

There will be no change in size of your APK. Method A will not increase the size of your APK because these are a compile-time construct only.

Comment: Thanks! Will Method A increase the size of APK package?

Comment: @HelloCW I updated my answer. There will be no change in size of your APK. Please check

Comment: Thanks! but Sagar told me the size of APK doesn't increase even if I use import utility.*, right?